# How to see the duplicates in a different columns in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, count, duplicates, having

I try to find the duplicates but at the same time be able to see it in a different columns but this duplicates is in the same report and also I verified the duplicates by year.

| report | id_tip | date | duration | source | tip | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1111212 | 31/12/22 | 9 | S04 | BS | 2 |
| 3456 | 2233242 | 20/10/22 | 80 | K34 | LS | 2 |

And this is the query I did in Oracle SQL Developer:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
        SELECT ID_PPAL_ICI AS report,
               BLNC_ID AS id_tip,
               BLNC_FEC_CIERRE AS date,
               BLNC_DUR AS duration,
               ID_PPAL_FNT AS source,
               BLNC_TIP AS tip,
               COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY ID_PPAL_ICI, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM BLNC_FEC_CIERRE)) AS cnt
                 
FROM   BLNC_BALANCES
  
    INNER JOIN ID_PPAL
    ON BLNC_ID_PPAL_ICI = ID_PPAL_ICI
         
ORDER BY BLNC_FEC_CIERRE DESC
)
WHERE  cnt > 1;

select * from BLNC_BALANCES;
```

But I would like to see a table like this:

| report | id_tip | date | duration | source | tip | id_tip_1 | date_1 | duration_1 | source_1 | tip_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1111212 | 31/12/22 | 9 | S04 | BS | 1122215 | 24/03/22 | 1 | S02 | BS |
| 3456 | 2233242 | 20/10/22 | 80 | K34 | LS | 4455385 | 15/02/22 | 11 | H12 | NS |

I've already try with a left join and HAVING COUNT but all I have is erros. Any help? please

Note: The amount of duplicates per row is at most one.

Comment: @lemon in this data is always 2 duplicate rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can self-join on mismatching dates, while keeping the partitioning of duplicates intact, by matching:

- "*report*" values
- year of "*date*" values

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ID_PPAL_ICI       AS report,
           BLNC_ID           AS id_tip,
           BLNC_FEC_CIERRE   AS date,
           BLNC_DUR          AS duration,
           ID_PPAL_FNT       AS source,
           BLNC_TIP          AS tip,
    FROM BLNC_BALANCES
    INNER JOIN ID_PPAL ON BLNC_ID_PPAL_ICI = ID_PPAL_ICI
)
SELECT t1.*,
       t2.id_tip   AS id_tip_1,
       t2.date     AS date_1,
       t2.duration AS duration_1,
       t2.source   AS source_1,
       t2.tip      AS tip_1
FROM       cte t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
        ON t1.report = t2.report 
       AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t1.date) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t2.date)
       AND NOT t1.date = t2.date
```